# Gerar cor unica para cada resultado

Tags: php, array

entao.. eu tenho um sistema de comentarios de forma anonima em um projeto meu que no lugar do avatar ele coloca a abreviação do nome da pessoa, por exemplo:

```
Vinicius Eduardo -> VE
```

e eu quero criar um sistema ou uma funcao que gere uma COR unica para cada abreviacao, para assim o usuario ser identificado com mais facilidade.

Resumindo tudo, eu tenho uma array contendo 24 cores em formato "#VLVLVL" e para cada abreviacao ele vai dar uma cor unica, por exemplo  VE -> #cccccc ED -> #000000 e se o VE comentar novamente a cor dele se repete como #cccccc

Comment: Então serão no máximo 24 abreviações? E se aparecer uma vigésima-quinta?

Comment: Concordo, apenas 24? O_O
Bom, mas se o site for pequeno não vejo problema :D

Comment: Usei 24 como um exemplo, se por acaso consigamos resolver essa questao eu aumentaria a tabela de cores com o tempo.

Comment: OK, a solução que postei suporta quantas cores tiver na array, quanto mais melhor, mas se o numero de usuários exceder o numero de cores o script para.

Comment: Brincando de design de interação: qual é o objetivo *da perspectiva do usuário*? É realmente diferenciar duas pessoas com a mesma abreviação (Vinicius Eduardo e Valeria Escobar, por exemplo) ou apenas diferenciar as abreviações nos comentários *exibidos* em uma tela? Se for o segundo, o número de cores necessárias tende a ser bem menor se não forem atribuidas de forma fixa. Além disso, talvez o contraste entre as cores seja mais importante do que a escolha da cor propriamente dita.

Comment: Se for mesmo o primeiro caso (diferenciar as pessoas), talvez você possa considerar a diferenciação por ocorrência de duplicidade. Tipo, não importaria se existissem um AP vermelho e um VE também vermelho, mas se existirem mais do que um VE ai sim eles seriam diferenciados por cores bastante distintas (apesar de ter uma combinação bastante grande de cores no RGB, a preocupação de fazê-las terem contraste suficiente deve diminuir um bocado esse número).

Comment: Gostei da sua forma de pensar, irei adaptar e usar!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considerando uma array de cores assim:

```
$cores = array('#000', '#333', '#666', '#999'); // do tamanho que você precisar
```

Eu criaria uma segunda array, associativa, onde você guarda as cores para cada usuário. Ela começa vazia:

```
$coresPorUsuario = array();
```

E a ideia é que ela passe a conter as cores dos usuários conforme eles vão surgindo. Por exemplo, `array('VE' => '#000', 'ED' => '#333')`.

Para controlar tudo, use uma função. Ela recebe as iniciais do usuário e devolve a cor correspondente. Se o usuário já existe em `$coresPorUsuario`, pega a cor que está lá. Se não existe, pega a próxima cor disponível, associa ao usuário, e devolve essa cor. Também será necessária uma variável para controlar qual é a próxima cor disponível.

```
$proxima = 0;    
function corUsuario($usuario) {

    global $cores;
    global $coresPorUsuario;
    global $proxima;

    // Usuário ainda não existe na array
    if(empty($coresPorUsuario[$usuario])) {
        // Guarda a cor do usuário e avança para a próxima cor disponível
        $coresPorUsuario[$usuario] = $cores[$proxima++];

        // Se passou da quantidade de cores disponíveis, começa novamente da primeira
        $proxima = $proxima == count($cores) ? 0 : $proxima;
    }

    // Retorna a cor do usuário
    return $coresPorUsuario[$usuario];
}
```

> **AVISO:** O exemplo acima usa variáveis globais por ser um caminho curto como exemplo. É provável que você queira implementar essa função como um método de uma classe. Nesse caso, use propriedades de instância em vez das variáveis globais.

Testando:

```
echo corUsuario('AA') . "\n"; // #000
echo corUsuario('AB') . "\n"; // #333
echo corUsuario('AC') . "\n"; // #666
echo corUsuario('AA') . "\n"; // #000
echo corUsuario('AD') . "\n"; // #999
echo corUsuario('AE') . "\n"; // #000
```

**[Demonstração](http://ideone.com/lLcXB9)**

Comment: Boa essa solução, se o número de cores esgotar, ele reinicia do 0,

Comment: É, aí fica a critério de quem usa o código decidir se acrescenta mais cores ou deixa a função rotacionar.

Comment: Hahah! chega ser bom ver um script funcionando corretamente,muito obrigado funcionou!

Answer (score 4):

Você pode criar uma array para as cores ja usadas e outra para as cores de cada usuário.

Eu poderia usar uma solução mais curta e prática, (e que alias usasse menos CPU..) mas queria que as cores fossem aleatorias.. mas como os usuários (ordenados por ID) já são aleatório o suficiente, acho a solução do bfavaretto melhor. Embora eu ache a solução dele mais prática e leve, vou manter a minha caso ainda tenho algum uso...

fiz uma simples "ilustração".

```
<?php
// Array para as cores de cada usuário.
# "NomeDeUsuario" => "COR HEX";
$usersColors = array();

// Array para as cores disponiveis [usei cores aleatorias]
$avaliableColors = array(
    0 => "#ececea",
    1 => "#efefef",
    2 => "#abcdef"
);

// Primeiro pegamos os usuários, eles são a parte importantes
$users = array(
    'banana123',
    'SouEUmesmo',
    'kitKat159',
);

// Se tiver mais usuários do que cores, abortar execução
if ( count($users) > count($avaliableColors) ) {
    die("ERRO: existem mais usuários do que cores.");
}

// Vamos criar uma array que guarda as cores ja usadas, pra não repeti-las
$alreadyUsed = array();
$userCount = count($users);
$colorCount = count($avaliableColors);

// Definindo uma cor aleatoria para cada um
for ($i=0;$i<$userCount;++$i) {
    // Numero aleatorio representando uma das cores.
    $max = $colorCount-1;
    $numeroAleatorio = rand(0, $max);

    if (in_array($numeroAleatorio, $alreadyUsed)) {
        // Se o numero ja tiver sido usado, ficar até encontrar um não utilizado
        $numeroNaoUsadoEncontrado = false;

        while ($numeroNaoUsadoEncontrado != true) {
            $numeroAleatorio = rand(0, $max);

            // Se o numero não tiver sido utilziado aidna
            if (!in_array($numeroAleatorio, $alreadyUsed)) {
                // Sair do loop de tentativas
                $numeroNaoUsadoEncontrado = true;

                // Colocar esse numero como já usado.
                $alreadyUsed[] = $numeroAleatorio;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // Colocar esse numero como já usado.
        $alreadyUsed[] = $numeroAleatorio;
    }

    // Agora que a cor ja foi escolhida, atribuir ela ao usuário
    $userName = $users[$i];
    $usersColors[$userName] = $avaliableColors[$numeroAleatorio];
}


# DEBUG
echo "<br>";
foreach ($usersColors as $user => $color) {
    echo $user . " -> " . $color . "<br/>\n";
}
```